# Geofence ENTER event triggered only once Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-geofence

I'm using Geofence events in my Android App.

As soon as geofences are registered, and I test my app for 2 nearby locations, I get Geofence ENTER trigger as expected, but when I revisit the locations, immediately, then no event is triggered.

My Geofence Expire time is NEVER.
And I never manually remove Geofences.

What could be the reason?

***Note:**

Internet was available

WiFi was ON (but was not connected)

GPS was ON

Comment: As with all gps related things, geofence measurements are not 100% accurate. It's possible your app didn't register that you exited the geofence yet when you re-entered it

Comment: Can you please post the code that you are using to create the geofences? If you used NEVER_EXPIRE then it should trigger your transitions IntentService whenever you enter again.

If you used a huge radius maybe you have never exited the geofence.
If you have rebooted your device, disabled/enabled location or cleared app data the geofences are removed. See all the cases here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: @Tim Castelijns......Do I need to register Geofence EXIT event too, to detect Geofence ENTER again?

Comment: Sorry I do not  know

Comment: Found any solution?

Comment: @pratiti-systematix you got any solution ?